# Past Time extention to display timeago in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, datetime, swift5

I found one of the extensions to display TimeAgo in swift and when I tried to use it and print the past time, it gives me error

> Value of type 'String?' has no member 'timeAgoDisplay'

Swift 5

extension I used

```
extension Date {
    func timeAgoDisplay() -> String {

        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let minuteAgo = calendar.date(byAdding: .minute, value: -1, to: Date())!
        let hourAgo = calendar.date(byAdding: .hour, value: -1, to: Date())!
        let dayAgo = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: Date())!
        let weekAgo = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: Date())!

        if minuteAgo < self {
            let diff = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: self, to: Date()).second ?? 0
            return "\(diff) sec ago"
        } else if hourAgo < self {
            let diff = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.minute], from: self, to: Date()).minute ?? 0
            return "\(diff) min ago"
        } else if dayAgo < self {
            let diff = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: self, to: Date()).hour ?? 0
            return "\(diff) hrs ago"
        } else if weekAgo < self {
            let diff = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: self, to: Date()).day ?? 0
            return "\(diff) days ago"
        }
        let diff = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekOfYear], from: self, to: Date()).weekOfYear ?? 0
        return "\(diff) weeks ago"
    }
}
```

how I use it

```
let PostTime = data!["time"].string
PostTime.timeAgoDisplay()
```

my time from db `2021-01-16 00:22:52` and I use datetime

I tried to converte to date using this and got nil

```js
   let PostTime = data!["time"].string!
        
        let startDate = PostTime
        
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy"
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: startDate)
        
        let converted = date?.timeAgoDisplay()
        DateLabel.text = date?.timeAgoDisplay()
```

Comment: Please look at your types. This is a `Date` extension but you try to use it on a `String`. This cannot work and this is what the error clearly says. You have to convert the string to `Date`.

Comment: @vadian tried with this and always I get nil    let PostTime = data!["time"].string!
        
        let startDate = PostTime
        
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy"
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: startDate)
        
        let converted = date?.timeAgoDisplay()
        DateLabel.text = date?.timeAgoDisplay()

Comment: The date format is wrong. The date part is dash separated and in a different order, and there is a time part colon separated.

Comment: @vadian thanks I managed to solve it using this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/relativedatetimeformatter but how to show it in my language other than english?

Comment: `RelativeDateTimeFormatter` can handle localized strings.

Comment: @vadian yes but my app is Arabic but it shows me english !

Comment: Do you use the [`localizedString`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/relativedatetimeformatter/3130998-localizedstring) API and is the locale of the device or simulator set properly?

Comment: @vadian yes this is what I used extension Date {
    func timeAgoDisplay() -> String {
        let formatter = RelativeDateTimeFormatter()
        formatter.unitsStyle = .full
        return formatter.localizedString(for: self, relativeTo: Date())
    }
}

Comment: As I said, the localization depends on the `locale` of the device / simulator. But honestly I'm not familiar with the behavior of non-latin languages.